# Можно ли выполнить какие-то действия при /logout в Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

Доброго времени суток друзья. Вопрос такой, можно ли выполнить какие-то изменения при /logout  (например изменения статуса текущего пользователя) в Spring Security. И как это сделать? Spring Security 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят. Для того чтобы выполнить что-то до logout пользователя, прибег к тому что мапил один адрес и с этого адрес уже редиректил на logout